# Best way to merge data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to merge the below data into one,
I am new to work in react, so not much sure.
Any thoughts how to merge this two data

```
var proone =
[
  {
    "brand": null,
    "url": "/product/make-me-purr-leopard-bralette-and-skirt-lingerie-set-s538619"
  }
]

var protwo =
{
  "brand": "MeMoi",
  "url": "/product/memoi-dot-flocked-sheer-tights.html",
}
```

Expected Output:

```
var prothree =
[
  {
    "brand": null,
    "url": "/product/make-me-purr-leopard-bralette-and-skirt-lingerie-set-s538619"
  },
  {
  "brand": "MeMoi",
  "url": "/product/memoi-dot-flocked-sheer-tights.html",
  }
]
```

Comment: So the `proone` always is an array and the `protwo` always is an object?

Comment: Yes, one is array & another is object

Comment: You can add elements to the array using the `push` function. Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: `var prothree = [...proone, protwo];`

Comment: Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'Array' | index 6 -> object with constructor 'Object' --- property 'products' closes the circle

This error appears

Answer (score 1):

Since proone is an array all you need to do is:

```
proone.push(protwo);
```

What you need to know about React, that many people seems to misunderstand, is that you for the most part just use standard javascript. The only thing that basically differs is the lifecycle, states and props.

Comment: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 6 -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'products' closes the circle

Comment: @devphp how so? Check the console tab, it works just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-minsky-e4sno?file=/src/index.js
Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

we are using ES6 so we can do it like this. Please try this one I hope it's helpful.

```js
 var proone =
[
  {
    "brand": null,
    "url": "/product/make-me-purr-leopard-bralette-and-skirt-lingerie-set-s538619"
  }
]

var protwo =
{
  "brand": "MeMoi",
  "url": "/product/memoi-dot-flocked-sheer-tights.html",
}

var result = [...proone,protwo];
console.log('result',result)
```

Comment: Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'Array' | index 2 -> object with constructor 'Object' --- property 'products' closes the circle

Comment: Trying with your code that error above mentioned appeared

Comment: Please give me your script here is it possible `https://jsfiddle.net/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use try like as below.

```js
var proone =
[
  {
    "brand": null,
    "url": "/product/make-me-purr-leopard-bralette-and-skirt-lingerie-set-s538619"
  }
]

var protwo =
{
  "brand": "MeMoi",
  "url": "/product/memoi-dot-flocked-sheer-tights.html",
}

var proneThree = [...proone, protwo]
console.log(proneThree, proneThree.length)
```

Comment: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 10 -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'products' closes the circl